# One to one correspondence between objects collection and ListBox rows

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

Is there any effective way to find the row of a sorted ListBox in WinAPI by the data connected with that row through sending of LB_SETITEMDATA message?
I have clients connecting to my server and need put their IPs in sorted ListBox so as user can click on a row and interract with the current client on the one hand and if client disconnects its record removed from ListBox on the other hand.
I have linked rows with SOCKETs by LB_SETITEMDATA for selecting client by click, but have not find message for getting row by linked data (not by string).
I found two macroses, name one of which is like it what I looking for, but inside I do not find out any significant differences between them. Experiment showed, that no one of two macroses or its messages not working (only searching by displayed string is correct).

Macroses:

```
#define ListBox_FindString(hwndCtl, indexStart, lpszFind) ((int)(DWORD)SNDMSG((hwndCtl), LB_FINDSTRING, (WPARAM)(int)(indexStart), (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(lpszFind)))
#define ListBox_FindItemData(hwndCtl, indexStart, data) ((int)(DWORD)SNDMSG((hwndCtl), LB_FINDSTRING, (WPARAM)(int)(indexStart), (LPARAM)(data)))
```

Next code show -1 in result, when I expect 1.

```
g_hListBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "ListBox", "Clients", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL|LBS_NOTIFY|LBS_SORT, 5, 40, 300, 500, g_hWnd,  (HMENU) LB_CLIENTS, hInstance, NULL);

    int a = SendMessage(g_hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"33333");
    SendMessage(g_hListBox, LB_SETITEMDATA, a, 6);
    int c = SendMessage(g_hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"11111"); 
    SendMessage(g_hListBox, LB_SETITEMDATA, c, 4);
    int b = SendMessage(g_hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"22222");
    SendMessage(g_hListBox, LB_SETITEMDATA, b, 5);

    char buf[15];
    int x = 5;
    MessageBox(g_hWnd,  itoa(ListBox_FindItemData(g_hListBox, -1, &x), buf, 10), "Function WSAStartup return",MB_OK);
```

Now I just send LB_GETITEMDATA to each row every time I need define index by data, and compare result with current data. It looks not rational, but it is written easy and can work.

Comment: A thought, add the socket as the item data, this is OBVIOUSLY windows code so the socket is nothing but an INT underneath all it's typedef's and defines. Then use the ListBox_FindItemData to get the index into the listbox the socket belongs, and then remove it.. or.. what ever.. And WHY on gods earth are you using those macros to begin with, WTL man , WTL.

Comment: ListBox_SetItemData(hwndCtl,itemIndex, (LPARAM)socket); sets the data on the index. ListBox_FindItemData(hwndctrl,idemIndex,(LPARAM)socket) returns the index assosaiated with the socket. ... you can also retrieve the data for the index, as in when a user clicks on an item with ListBox_GetItemData .. But your using really really old techniques to do this, There's libraries out there for working with Windows, WTL (windows template library) IMHO is much easier to work with than dealing with raw win32 api. To note, on the ListBox_Find macro's, the index you pass in , is the index the search starts

Comment: I know that there are more high-level ways to do this, but I need make it in pure WinAPI. And the problem is that ListBox_FindItemData don't find row by connected with it data (socket in my case).

Comment: are you casting it into the macro as a (LPARAM) ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ListBox_FindItemData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro that does what you want.

This uses the [LB_FINDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message that says it can match based on the "Long value that matches"

> LB_FINDSTRING attempts to find an item that has a long value (supplied as the lParam parameter of the LB_ADDSTRING or LB_INSERTSTRING message) that matches the lParam parameter.

Comment: But I can't make it work. Moreover it even use LB_FINDSTRING, that find only by string not by item data isn't it?

Comment: it works for me. all i can tell ya., Item data and item text are two different things. The data is like a tag that can be added to the item. It may use LB_FINDSTRING on both searches, searching both item string and tag, but it'll return the correct result either way. Check the macro's to set and get the item data, they use completely different widnows messages than the ones for getting and setting the text

Comment: Also to note, when the lb is set to LB_SORT the system sends LB_COMPAREITEM when trying to find anything. not LB_FINDSTRING , it does this under the hood... without your intervention. So, you might want to also compare the COMPAREITEMDATA struct's data portion as well as the string portion to determine your actual value, i can tell you straight up that the listbox uses a binary search when it's sorted to find anything, so your comparision should always be  less than, or greater than. NOT equal.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Looking at the macro, `ListBox_FindItemData` uses `LB_FINDSTRING` but casts the data direct to `LPARAM` From MSDN, "Otherwise, LB_FINDSTRING attempts to find an item that has a long value (supplied as the lParam parameter of the LB_ADDSTRING or LB_INSERTSTRING message) that matches the lParam parameter." but it's not clear whether it does this if it's not owner drawn.

Comment: But "supplied as the lParam parameter of the LB_ADDSTRING or LB_INSERTSTRING message" is
"lParam
A pointer to the null-terminated string that is to be added.
If the list box has an owner-drawn style but not the LBS_HASSTRINGS style, this parameter is stored as item data instead of a string. You can send the LB_GETITEMDATA and LB_SETITEMDATA messages to retrieve or modify the item data." So may be it work only for the list box has an owner-drawn style but not the LBS_HASSTRINGS? Otherwise it would be ambiguous if item data match also a letter first in other showing string.

Comment: @SerG, when you created the listbox, you created it with LB_SORT flags, as you said it was sorted, i presume you did. In that case the listbox control will send your window back a WM_COMPAREITEM message, which you must handle to determine sorting, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx,  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .

Comment: @SerG it will also use this 'sort' to FIND an item.

Comment: @johnathon, it's used with **owner-drawn** style. My main window does not receive such message from ListBox.

Comment: @SerG Then how are you sorting your data in the listbox? Are you presorting it?

Comment: I use LB_SORT as you mean.

Comment: if your using LB_SORT, you will get a WM_COMPAREITEM message. Handle the message, and sort the data to your requirments. then your find will work. Note, you'll have to set a bool fag for when your comparing strings, or comparing the data.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you switch to a virtual ListBox or virtual ListView instead, storing the actual data in your own list/array/whatever as needed, sorted however you want.  The ListBox/ListView simply displays what is in your list, the data is not actually stored in the ListBox/ListView itself.  This way, when you need to find something, you look in your own storage, not in the UI.  This also provides performance benefits, and gives you more control over data management, caching, etc.